# Python Scrapy : Response Body shows nothing but Redirecting

Tags: python, html, scrapy

Im trying to build a scraper that scrapes the Google Developer Console Account. When I run the spider , it seem to log-in successfully and the logs are coming out fine. When I tried to request another page and write the response.body to a file. It gives out the following (**response.html**) :

> `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Redirecting...</title><script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">var url = 'https:\/\/accounts.google.com\/ServiceLogin?service\x3dandroiddeveloper\x26passive\x3d1209600\x26continue\x3dhttps:\/\/play.google.com\/apps\/publish\/?dev_acc%3D14813004207305910035%23__HASH__\x26followup\x3dhttps:\/\/play.google.com\/apps\/publish\/?dev_acc%3D14813004207305910035'; var fragment = ''; if (self.document.location.hash) {fragment = self.document.location.hash.replace(/^#/,'');}url = url.replace(new RegExp("__HASH__", 'g'), encodeURIComponent(fragment));window.location.assign(url);</script><noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url='https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service&#61;androiddeveloper&amp;passive&#61;1209600&amp;continue&#61;https://play.google.com/apps/publish/?dev_acc%3D14813004207305910035&amp;followup&#61;https://play.google.com/apps/publish/?dev_acc%3D14813004207305910035'"></meta></noscript></head><body></body></html>`

So basically i understand it to be a plain html with no body and title --> Redirecting...

I'm assuming the spider is crawling before even the page is loading. I researched and tried adding `meta={'handle_httpstatus_list': [302],'dont_redirect': True}` to Request , there seems no difference.

Here's my spider :

```
from scrapy.http import FormRequest, Request
import  logging
import scrapy

class LoginSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'super'
    start_urls = ['https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=androiddeveloper&passive=1209600&continue=https://play.google.com/apps/publish/%23&followup=https://play.google.com/apps/publish/#identifier']

def parse(self, response):
    return [FormRequest.from_response(response,
                formdata={'Email': 'devaccnt@gmail.com', 'Passwd': 'devpwd'},

                callback=self.after_login)]

def after_login(self, response):
    if "wrong" in str(response.body):
        self.log("Login failed", level=logging.ERROR)
        return
# We've successfully authenticated, let's have some fun!
    print("Login Successful!!")
    return Request(url="https://play.google.com/apps/publish/?dev_acc=14592564207369815#AppListPlace", meta={'handle_httpstatus_list': [302],
                           'dont_redirect': True},
           callback=self.parse_tastypage)


def parse_tastypage(self, response):
    print ("---------------------")
    filename = 'response.html'
    print(filename)
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.body)
    print ("---------------------")
```

** Don't mind the indents, they're fine in the original script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think is happening is actually the opposite, that is that Scrapy is **not following the redirect**. Here's a sample scrapy shell session where you can see that the HTTP response code is 200, not 302:

```
$ scrapy shell 'https://play.google.com/apps/publish/?dev_acc=14592564207369815#AppListPlace'
2017-02-07 10:30:45 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.3.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
(...)
2017-02-07 10:30:45 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://play.google.com/apps/publish/?dev_acc=14592564207369815#AppListPlace> (referer: None)
>>> print(response.text)
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Redirecting...</title><script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">var url = 'https:\/\/accounts.google.com\/ServiceLogin?service\x3dandroiddeveloper\x26passive\x3d1209600\x26continue\x3dhttps:\/\/play.google.com\/apps\/publish\/?dev_acc%3D14592564207369815%23__HASH__\x26followup\x3dhttps:\/\/play.google.com\/apps\/publish\/?dev_acc%3D14592564207369815'; var fragment = ''; if (self.document.location.hash) {fragment = self.document.location.hash.replace(/^#/,'');}url = url.replace(new RegExp("__HASH__", 'g'), encodeURIComponent(fragment));window.location.assign(url);</script><noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url='https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service&#61;androiddeveloper&amp;passive&#61;1209600&amp;continue&#61;https://play.google.com/apps/publish/?dev_acc%3D14592564207369815&amp;followup&#61;https://play.google.com/apps/publish/?dev_acc%3D14592564207369815'"></meta></noscript></head><body></body></html>
```

Scrapy does not interpret JavaScript but it should be able to understand this:

```
<noscript>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url='https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service&#61;androiddeveloper&amp;passive&#61;1209600&amp;continue&#61;https://play.google.com/apps/publish/?dev_acc%3D14813004207305910035&amp;followup&#61;https://play.google.com/apps/publish/?dev_acc%3D14813004207305910035'">
</meta>
</noscript>
```

But it does not.

The part of the framework responsible for this kind of meta-refresh redirects is [`scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/db408528928b2d15043593032913fe40d6eb6783/scrapy/downloadermiddlewares/redirect.py#L81)

It is currently implemented to look for meta-refresh info that are NOT in `<script>` or `<noscript>` (see [`scrapy.utils.response.get_meta_refresh`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/129421c7e31b89b9b0f9c5f7d8ae59e47df36091/scrapy/utils/response.py#L34))

You can change this with a custom `MetaRefreshMiddleware` which looks for the meta-refresh also inside `<noscript>` elements:

```
>>> w3lib.html.get_meta_refresh(response.text, response.url, response.encoding, ignore_tags=('script'))
(0.0, 'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=androiddeveloper&passive=1209600&continue=https://play.google.com/apps/publish/?dev_acc%3D14592564207369815&followup=https://play.google.com/apps/publish/?dev_acc%3D14592564207369815')
```

Comment: hi thanks for the answer, it helped me to understand the whole thing much better, but after doing whatever you have suggested it still gives me the same response. I have enabled. I followed the steps in this [link] (https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html) to enable a custom middleware and disable the existing meta refresh middleware. and I have added the code to ignore only 'script' tags, still same response

Comment: Its working , I forgot to remove the dont_redirect tag , after that it was working. Thanks :)